# How to set an element's height same as its width and keep the size ratio on window resize?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, height, width

I am trying to set the height of an element same as its width. It should be auto-scaling/ keep size ratio according to web browser resolution changes. Is there a way to do that with only html template? Something like:

```
<div class="tile" #square [ngStyle]="{'height.px': square.width}">
```

Comment: I think You need to use `JavaScript` & `CSS`

Comment: do you know the width of the `div`? are you setting it using the `tile` class ?

Comment: You didn't know about `offsetWidth`?

Comment: width is setted in scss as 25%.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to use the element's offsetWidth, but we also need to silent the window resizing to keep the ratio

**HTML:**

```
  <div #square (window:resize)="0" [ngStyle]="{'height.px': square.offsetWidth }">
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ndqnc?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: as I understand, OP doesn't want to set a hard-coded height !

Comment: The difference is the ability to keep the ratio on the window resize

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `square.offsetWidth`:

```
<div 
    class="tile"
    #square
    [ngStyle]="{'height.px': square.offsetWidth}"    
>
```

Link to [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qeeepb?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).