# Angular 8 make an element square throws Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm trying to make a div square dynamically. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301846/1792537).

```
<div #div (window:resize)="0" [ngStyle]="{'height.px': div?.offsetWidth || 1 }">
```

However it throws error;

```
SiparisGirComponent.html:98 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: 
Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'height.px: 1'. Current value: 
'height.px: 135'.
```

It does work, but the error disturbs me. Can anyone help me to get rid of that error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually you could make use of CSS trick what gives you div with any ratio based on simple padding property. Here you can take a look at few examples. I'm sure it would be enough if you need to get height by width https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp

Answer (score 2):

This is because in dev mode angular checks that the values have not changed after updating the bindings. Having the values change in between could cause side effect, like not having the correct value displayed (see a good explanation [here](https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error/))

In your example:

- change detection runs
- the div is not created yet
- angular assigns  the value 1 to the div's `style.height` property
- the browser draws the div
- angular runs change detection again (in dev mode only)
- the div exists, and so the `style.height` value would not be 1 anymore. Angular then throws an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error

You need to notify angular about the change using `ChangeDectorRef.detectChanges()`. To do that, you can call a component's method, since you cannot call it directly from the template.

**component.ts**

```
  lastWidth = 1;
  @ViewChild('div', {static: true}) div: ElementRef;
  constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef)
  {

  }

  getWidth()
  {
    if(this.div)//Wzit until element is created
    {
       //Only call detectChanges if the previous value has changed
      if(this.div.nativeElement.offsetWidth  != this.lastWidth)
      {
        this.lastWidth = this.div.nativeElement.offsetWidth ;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }
    }
    return this.lastWidth;

  }
```

**component.html**

```
<div #div  (window:resize)="0" [ngStyle]="{'height.px': getHeight() }">
```

I created  a stackblitz [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ye5ynf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) where you can resize the div's dynamically.

Note: you could also wrap the change in a `setTimeout` call, which would also solve the issue. However, this will run change detection again for the whole application, not just the component that you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

It works in development mode, but it propably won't work correctly in production build. Try to look at this [article](https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error/), to understand what this error means.

To get rid of this error, you can manually force [Change Detection](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) to run again, after you set the height.

I created simple [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rezqjc)

**HTML:**

```
<div #div (window:resize)="0" [ngStyle]="{'height.px': dynamicDivHeight }"></div>
```

**TS:**

```
...
export class Component implements AfterViewInit  {

    @ViewChild('div', { static: false } ) div: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>; // element reference

    dynamicDivHeight: number = 1;

    constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }


    ngAfterViewInit() {    // if you are working with native html elements, you should be doing it in AfterViewInit hook
        this.dynamicDivHeight = this.div.nativeElement.offsetWidth;     // set the dynamic height
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();     // manually force change detection
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue only comes in development mode. It is introduced in Angular to avoid the issue of the cycle in digest cycle (Problem in AngularJS).

After running the change detection cycle successfully over the bindings, Angular again does checking on bindings if they have changed or not once again by running change detection. And if any of the values changes, Angular throws this error in console.

Please go through this interesting blog to understand [Change detection in Angular and meaning of this error](https://indepth.dev/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular/)

As told, this is because  Angular run another cycle to check if value of any binding has changed or not. So, you can easily skip the consecutive change by running asynchronously using setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.lastWidth = this.div.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
});
```

You can also use a change-detection manually as answered above.

Please see this working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nvwium'

Comment: `setTimeout` triggers change detection for the whole application, whereas `detectionChanges` only does it for the current component and its children.